# PhpStorm - Remove underlining of SQL statement in PHP

Tags: phpstorm, color-scheme

I'm using PhpStorm with the Monokai scheme.
When I write an SQL statement in PHP they get underlined. Where can I disable/change this? See images below.
I've looked in Color & Fonts but can't seem to find the place to change it.
I'm used to the Monokai scheme so I would like to keep using it.

In Monokai scheme:

[image: Monokai scheme]

In Dracula scheme:

[image: Dracula]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the result of code formatting, rather than PHPStorm's error detection? If you don't have a [data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/data-sources.html) configured, PHPStorm marks all SQL statements with a warning to inform you that it can't validate your SQL against the DB schema, that might be the case here.

Comment: Yes, could be, but why doesn't it show when using the Dracula theme?
And how can I disable this warning? This is what I get when I Alt+Enter:  [link](http://i.imgur.com/nOnjh8l.png)

Comment: Settings > Editor > Inspections > SQL > No data sources configured > uncheck checkbox. Does that help? (It does not show an underline in Darcula because the Darcula theme styles warnings that way.)

Comment: Unchecking that and 'SQL dialect dectection' did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see there is a `warning` from one of the SQL Inspections.

Your options:

1. Fix the actual issue that Inspection is warning you about
2. Disable that inspection (those inspections, if there are more than one warning) at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Inspections | SQL`
3. Change SQL dialect from specific (e.g. `MySQL`) to `Generic` where you will have only generic syntax highlighting and no SQL code validation will be performed (no code helpers will be available)
4. Change style for actual "Warning": `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Warning` (NOTE: If Monokai is bundled theme (not installed by you) then you will have to create your own copy before making changes as bundled schemes cannot be modified)

Comment: thank you! my framework uses templated sql and doxygen (with @retval instead of @return) comments and the amount of underlining for non-error "errors" was getting extreme.